# Is there a way to create shared Gradle file which contains plugins?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

For example :

**springboot.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: file("$envDir/springboot.gradle")
```

When I tried to do that I get the error : **Plugin with id 'org.springframework.boot' not found.** 
but if I doing that from specific file ( apply the plugin) it works..